# How to handle the handler exception?

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I'm updating the volley data using handler it works fine, when I'm scrolling down for swipe refresh, then also it works fine but when I want to go down and I'm scrolling down to up the app got crashed and closed automatically.
here is the code of handler.

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
         loadDataFromServer();
         handler.postDelayed(this, 200);
     }
  };Handler.postDelayed(runnable, 200) ;
```

error log is here

```
05-16 09:23:16.697 19724-19724/com.messenger.nillrong E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.messenger.nillrong, PID: 19724
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid item position 8(offset:8).state:9 android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView{58bee7e VFED..... .F...... 0,0-1080,1845 #7f08007b app:id/recyclerViewId}, adapter:com.messenger.nillrong.MyRecyclerAdapter@2b31fdf, layout:android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager@f74b42c, context:com.messenger.nillrong.MainActivity@5452394
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5817)
    at android.support.v7.widget.GapWorker.prefetchPositionWithDeadline(GapWorker.java:285)
    at android.support.v7.widget.GapWorker.flushTaskWithDeadline(GapWorker.java:342)
    at android.support.v7.widget.GapWorker.flushTasksWithDeadline(GapWorker.java:358)
    at android.support.v7.widget.GapWorker.prefetch(GapWorker.java:365)
    at android.support.v7.widget.GapWorker.run(GapWorker.java:396)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6342)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:880)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:770)
 05-16 09:23:16.765 19724-19724/com.messenger.nillrong I/Process: Sending signa
```

Comment: `the app got crashed and closed automatically`; please share the stack trace and the relevant code

Comment: Please post your crash log, So we can analyse  it and give you some suggestions.

Comment: error log added.